# How to merge a drive with primary boot partition in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, disk

I would like to merge my G drive with C drive as i need more space in primary boot partition(C drive).. But C and G drives are not physically adjacent in my computer. I have D and E drives in between. I have emptied G drive. I want to merge G drive because i could easily free it up as it has smaller size. I am using Windows 8. Kindly help me to merge these two drives without affecting my C drive..

Answer (score 0):

Usually the partitions must be adjacent for beeing merged with windows tools.
There are other tools that allow this, e.g. [Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/extend-partition.html).

Partition Wizard offers a free [Home Edition](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) but this edition won't allow merging non adjacent partitions. Compare the [features](http://partitionwizard.com/comparison.html) of the different editions.